# Can't set type to Array<string> in flow-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I have following error from flow in one before the last line of function getRowData:

> message: 'Cannot call `getRow` with `el.arr` bound to `data` because:
>   Either property `arr` of unknown type [1] is incompatible with array
>   type [2]. Or property `arr` of unknown type [1] is incompatible with
>   string [3]. (References: [1] [2] [3])' at: '60,44' source: 'flow'
>   code: 'undefined'

This error is disappearing only if I change `Array<string>` in `type UserProps` to `Array<mixed>`, but I'd like to stay with the array of strings.

I don't understand why I get this error. I explicitly set `data.audio` and `data.chat` to `Array<string>`. Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
type UserProps = {
  name: string,
  audio: Array<string>,
  chat: Array<string>,
  enableChat: boolean,
  enableAudio: boolean,
  status: string,
};

const getRow = (key, data: string[] | string, style = {}) => {
  const text = Array.isArray(data) ? data.join(", ") : data;
  return (
    <TableRowColumn
      key={`row-${key}`}
      style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", ...style }}
    >
      {text}
    </TableRowColumn>
  );
};

const getRowData = (data: UserProps) =>
  [
    data.name,
    data.status,
    {
      arr: data.audio,
      style: { color: data.enableAudio ? "green" : "red" }
    },
    { arr: data.chat, style: { color: data.enableChat ? "green" : "red" } }
  ].map(
    (el, i) =>
      el && el.arr && el.style ? getRow(i, el.arr, el.style) : getRow(i, el) // error in el.arr !!!!!
  );
```

Comment: Newbie question, but : is `Array<string>` equal to `string[]` ?

Comment: Yes, same error with string[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is a bit confusing, but the problem is that flow fails to refine the `el` type. What you can do to is slightly change the refinement:

```
typeof el === 'string' ? getRow(i, el) : getRow(i, el.arr, el.style)
```

You can try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#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-MpRAepwetEgA)

Answer (score 1):

`getDataRow` does not have an annotated return type, so its implied by the return value, which is an array consisting of string, string, object, object, which is then passed through `map` (which returns the same type as the input).  `el` in the `map` callback is therefore `string | object`.

Flow can't determine if `arr` is a property of string or object. It could be undefined (I've found problems with flow's interpretation of compound logical tests like you have in `el && el.arr && el.style`.  If you spell them out as `if` statements they work as expected, but logical `&&` and `||` seems problematic).

As a result, flow thinks `el.arr` is not compatible with the second argument of `getRow` which requires `string[] | string`.

You'd need to determine the type of `el` before accessing the properties for flow to be happy. Testing for the presence of members `arr` and `style` does not do that (although you might want to look at Disjoint Unions as a way of doing so, if your types are malleable, but I think that's wouldn't work in this case because you have no option but to use the stock definition of `string`).

As a side note, whilst the shorthand array syntax (`{type}[]`) can be convenient, it can be confusing with optional or maybe values before you have less scope for where the `?` goes.  As a result, I have opted to use the longhand `Array<{type}>` syntax.  There's more in the docs on the subject.